# Batch command line arguments separated with && not interpreted as a single argument

Tags: batch-file, cmd, msys2

I have this useful batch script named `lxss.cmd` added to my PATH:

```
::@ECHO OFF
@ECHO ON
set arg1=%*
"C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" -c "%arg1%"
```

Which is outputting:

```bash
User@LANTI-DESKTOP C:\Users\User
$ lxss lsb_release -a && uname -a

User@LANTI-DESKTOP C:\Users\User
$ set arg1=lsb_release -a

User@LANTI-DESKTOP C:\Users\User
$ "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" -c "lsb_release -a"
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
MSYS_NT-10.0 LANTI-DESKTOP 2.6.1(0.305/5/3) 2017-01-25 00:01 x86_64 Msys
```

As you can see, the `uname -a` command left from this execution, but instead run by MSYS2 which is also presented in my PATH. Probably the `&&` command also handled by MSYS2. But this won't be a problem if `set arg1=lsb_release -a` line would be containing `&& uname -a` also.

My expected output that I want to achieve:

```bash
User@LANTI-DESKTOP C:\Users\User
$ "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" -c "lsb_release -a && uname -a"
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
Linux LANTI-DESKTOP 3.4.0+ #1 PREEMPT Thu Aug 1 17:06:05 CST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I found the `%*` variable [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466249/how-can-i-pass-a-space-separated-variable-into-a-bat-file/3472543#3472543), but looks like `&&` terminating the readout. Is there a way to achieve what I want?

**Edit:**

As reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8055430/1442219) the Windows and Linux `&&` command basically doing the same thing.

So I edited slightly my script: `"C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" -c %*`

And now I executing with this command: `lxss "lsb_release -a && uname -a"`

Which is works, but would be much nicer with less typing and look as linux like as possible. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that `&&` is a consitional command separator, which needs to be in between quotation marks or escaped like `^&^&` in order not to be recognised by the parser and therefore not to be executed. You need to show how you provide the arguments...

Comment: It's in the first commandline, this is what I enter to execute: `$ lxss lsb_release -a && uname -a`. Somehow not possible to write a regex to always replace `&&` with `^&^&` for `arg1`?

Comment: The batch file is executed by `cmd`, the Windows command processor, which consumes the `&&` on its own. Why are you trying to use the batch fie after all?

Comment: I tried to save so much typing as much as I can, but looks like I need to deal with the commas. Because other `bash`es presented in my PATH, I include the full directory for `bash.exe`, which I not want to type every time, plus I want to replace `clang` and `clang-format` for Sublime Text from MSYS2 by the LXSS equivalent ones.